# Problems with solving a 2 variable limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is this exercise I'm trying to solve but can't seem to get it, it states the following:

Study the continuity in the origin (depending of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$) of $$f_\alpha(x,y) = \frac{x^6y^3}{(x^8+y^6)^\alpha}$$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $$f_\alpha(x,y) = 0$$ when $(x,y) = (0,0)$

I have tried various methods, passing to polar coordinates and so on but can't really seem to get anywhere, I know the only possible candidate for the limit is $0$ and thats the result I got several times, so I'm guessing it is continous at $0$ (maybe I'm wrong) and I would have to prove this using the definition but don't know how to do it.

Any hints are appreciated and sorry for my broken English.

Comment: The answer will depend on the value of $\alpha$. Have you tried plotting it for different values?

Comment: If $x=y=t$ this expression becomes $t^9\over(t^8+t^6)^\alpha$ with $t\to 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we switch to polar coordinates, we have $$f_{\alpha}(r,\varphi)=\frac{r^9cos^6(\varphi)sin^3(\varphi)}{(r^8cos^8(\varphi)+r^6sin^6(\varphi))^{\alpha}}=r^{9-6\alpha}\frac{cos^6(\varphi)sin^3(\varphi)}{(r^2cos^8(\varphi)+sin^6(\varphi))^{\alpha}}$$

If we now let $r$ go to $0$, the fraction part is bounded and $r^{9-6\alpha}$ goes either to $0$ if $6\alpha<9\Leftrightarrow \alpha<\frac{3}{2}$ or to infinity if $6\alpha>9\Leftrightarrow \alpha>\frac{3}{2} $.

From this, you can deduct when $f_{\alpha}$ is continous. Don't forget the case where $\alpha=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Okay, got it. For $\alpha = \frac{3}{2}$ I used the hint from one of the comments above (x = y = t) substitution and got that the limit is equal to $0$ Am I correct?

Comment: If $\alpha=\frac{3}{2}$, we get $$f_{\alpha}(r,\varphi)=\frac{cos^6(\varphi)sin^3(\varphi)}{(sin^6(\varphi))^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ for $r=0$ which clearly depends on $\varphi$. Therefore, the limit does not exist if $\alpha=\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: How did you make the $r^2cos^8\phi$ dissapear?

Comment: We can just set $r=0$ here.

Comment: Ahhhh okay, got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

By polar coordinates for $\alpha<\frac32$ the limit is clearly equal to zero.

For $\alpha\ge \frac32$ by $x=t$ and $y=t$ with $t\to0$

$$ \frac{x^6y^3}{(x^8+y^6)^\alpha}= \frac{t^9}{(t^8+t^6)^\alpha}= \frac{1}{(t^{8-\frac9{\alpha}}+t^{6-\frac9{\alpha}})^\alpha}$$

which tends to $1$, when $\alpha=3/2$ or $\infty$, when $\alpha>3/2$.